# How to open .ProcSpec files in python?

Tags: python

I have [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iF8S_Wxcl45bPjH7q2y10h9ZG3RrUL_y/view?usp=sharing) obtained from SpectraSuite software (Processed spectrum, OOI Binary File), I tried to open it with

```
f = open(r'C:\Users\path/file.ProcSpec', 'rb')
    file_content = f.read()
f.close()
```

but file_content is data like "b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x00\x08\x007t\x...".
How can I open this type of file as tabular data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**

From within Spectra Suite you can open and export them again while setting the file type to be `Tab Delimited`. Then you should be able to import them with the csv lib.

[image]

See how to open csv files [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/54251/versions/1/previews/importoceanoptics.m/index.html).

**From Python directly**

[Here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/54251/versions/1/previews/importoceanoptics.m/index.html) is a Matlab code which does what you want.

From the Matlab code we see that the OOI formatat is a zipped xml. Also there seem to be some characters which cannot be parsed by a XML parser.

Knowing this, the files can be opened with the following code. Note that this is a quick implementation without error handling or thorough testing.

```
import os
import shutil
import glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import numpy as np

def parseNodeText(node):
        # bool
        nodeText = node.text
        if 'true' == nodeText or 'false' == nodeText:
            return nodeText == 'true'
        # int
        try:
            return int(nodeText)
        except:
            pass
        # float
        try:
            return float(nodeText)
        except:
            pass
        # text
        return nodeText

def extractArrayFromNode(node):
    arr = []
    for val in node:
        arr.append(parseNodeText(val))
    if 'double' in node[0].tag:
        dt = np.float32
    elif 'int' in node[0].tag:
        dt = np.int32
    else:
        dt = np.float32
    return np.array(arr,dtype=dt)
    

def readProcSpecFile(filePath):
    
    dirName = os.path.dirname(filePath)
    
    tmpdir = os.path.join(dirName,'tmp')
    os.makedirs(tmpdir, exist_ok=True)
    tmpFile= os.path.join(tmpdir,'tmp.zip')
    shutil.copy(filePath, tmpFile)
    shutil.unpack_archive(tmpFile, tmpdir)
    
    for f in glob.glob(tmpdir+r'\*.xml'):
        if 'OOISignatures.xml' in f:
            continue
        
        with open(f,"rb") as fi:
            s = fi.read()
       
        badChars = [b'\xa0',b'\x89',b'\x80'] 
        for c in badChars:
            s = s.replace(c,b' ')
            
        with open(f,"wb") as fi:
            fi.write(s)
        
        tree = ET.parse(f.encode("utf-8"))
        root = tree.getroot()
          
        result = [] 
        for spectra in root[0]:
            s = spectra[0]
            spect = {}
            for node in spectra:
                t = node.tag
                n = parseNodeText(node)
                if t == 'pixelValues':
                    spect[t] = extractArrayFromNode(node)
                elif t == 'channelWavelengths':
                    spect[t] = extractArrayFromNode(node)
                elif t == 'acquisitionTime':
                    times =  {}
                    for val in node:
                        times[val.tag] =  parseNodeText(val)
                    spect[t] = times
                    
                elif t == 'certificates':
                    pass
                elif t == 'channelCoefficients':
                    pass
                
                else:
                    spect[t] = n
            result.append(spect)  
        shutil.rmtree(tmpdir)
        return result
```

Here is an example on how to use it:

```
iFile = r'your\path\file.ProcSpec'
spects = readProcSpecFile(iFile)
spect = spects[0]  
print(spect.keys())
wavelength = spect['channelWavelengths']
pixelValues = spect['pixelValues']
```

This is the output:

```
dict_keys(['saturated', 'integrationTime', 'strobeEnabled', 'strobeDelay', 'pixelValues', 'acquisitionTime', 'boxcarWidth', 'scansToAverage', 'correctForElectricalDark', 'correctForNonLinearity', 'correctForStrayLight', 'rotationEnabled', 'userName', 'channelWavelengths', 'channelNumber', 'channelStabilityScanEnabled', 'channelExternalTriggerEnabled', 'laserWavelength', 'interlock', 'numberOfPixels', 'numberOfDarkPixels', 'spectrometerSerialNumber', 'spectrometerFirmwareVersion', 'spectrometerClass', 'spectrometerPlugins', 'spectrometerNumberOfChannels', 'spectrometerMaximumIntensity', 'spectrometerMinimumIntegrationTime', 'spectrometerMaximumIntegrationTime', 'spectrometerIntegrationTimeStep', 'spectrometerIntegrationTimeBase', 'spectrometerNumberOfPixels', 'spectrometerNumberOfDarkPixels'])

In [2]:wavelength
Out[2]:array([ 199.51251,  199.98462,  200.4567 , ..., 1116.266  , 1116.6813 ,
       1117.0964 ], dtype=float32)

In [3]:pixelValues
Out[3]:array([64000. ,  1958.1,  1958.1, ...,  1957.1,  1957.1,  1957.5],
      dtype=float32)
```

Here is a plot of the `wavelength` and `values` arrays:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I found out those ways as well. But the problem is I have hundreds of files of this type and I don't want to manually open them in the software and save them again as tab-delimited, it'll take too long. I am not familiar with MatLab so the other solution is not something I can do. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: It appears `shutil.unpack_archive` doesn't recognize .procspec files as an archive but it worked after I replaced file extension with .zip. Still ET.parse gives me the following error `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 4300, column 39`

Comment: the replacement doesn't work unless you replace `" "` with `b" "` even after that I still get the previous error. How do I know which characters to add to `badChars` ?

Comment: I completly reworked my answer. Hope this now fully covers your question,